# enabling scroll view scroll to top

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview in a subview.How to enable `setScrollsToTop` on status bar click?

I have tried `[DetailView.scrollView setScrollsToTop:YES];` and `[scrollview setScrollsToTop:YES];`

Still doesn't work. DetailView is my subView.Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

iOS automatically decides what to do on status bar click based on several factors - like currently active scroll view to position onscreen to position in the view hierarchy.

Setting `scrollsToTop` only tells iOS that you are OK with this behavior.